# Vote count in Users->voters is off

Tags: bug, status-completed, votes

Right now, my [MathOverflow user page](https://mathoverflow.net/users/121/s-carnahan) shows 12,878 votes, but the [page with people's overall vote counts](https://mathoverflow.net/users?tab=voters&filter=all) shows a mere 8674.  I see similar discrepancies with other people's accounts.  Is there some unorthodox enumeration method at work?

Comment: I _believe_ this is because you're seeing votes on deleted posts in your profile, which is not even considered on the other page. I'm pretty sure that's it but I'll confirm just to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it.  My initial impression is that 4204 is a surprisingly large number of deleted posts.

Comment: @TimPost The summary page of the profile doesn't show deleted votes but does include votes cast on deleted posts. The Voters tab should basically show you the same thing. It is, however, cached. The thing that's puzzling me here is why we don't get an up-to-date value since the site basically just went up. Maybe it has something to do with the pre-migration test instance. Either way, I'd wait a few days to see if the value updates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several places where we assume the [Community User's](https://mathoverflow.net/users/-1/community) creation date is when the site was created - one of those places is on the /users list page for the "all" filters.

For whatever reason*, Community's creation date was incorrect, having a value of `2010-11-10`, instead of `2009-09-28`, or when [Anton's user](https://mathoverflow.net/users/1/anton-geraschenko) was created.  This would result in over a year of your votes not being aggregated.

I've updated Community to have the proper date, so everything should be fixed.

<sub>* I think it's because the old SE1.0 codebase didn't use this date for anything, so it wasn't imperative for it to be correct.</sub>

Comment: Yes, it it seems to be fine now.  Thanks a lot!